Distance needed for visible light to be cosmologically redshifted to microwave
What distance will it take for visible light to become a microwave due to cosmological redshift?
I'm not sure how to calculate this, as I'm never good at complex math. I tried googling but didn't find much info about this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you asking about light traveling through an expanding universe, like the Cosmic Microwave Background did?

@mmesser314 yes I am.

What you want is the redshift (Z value), not the distance traveled. They are only vaguely related.

What do you understand by 'pure white light'? In my book this means an incoherent superposition of all frequencies with the same intensity. I suspect that that is not what you intended to say.

When the light travels the intensity of the light gets decreased( inverse square law ) but the energy and momentum of the light photon be same it doesn't gets change,
If you are asking about the how the light(visible light) converted to microwave,
ie, wavelength gets increased( frequency gets decreased) If frequency gets decreased so the source of the light is moving away from the observer and by using the Doppler shift you can calculate the how fast the source is moving away from us.

Just an FYI, visible light is all light between 380 nanometers (violet) to 700 nanometers (red), and microwave light is typically 300MHz to 300GHz (1 millimeter to 30 centimeters). If my understanding is correct, the question is then, how much distance does light need to travel to stretch from 380nm to get to 30cm wavelength (longest) or from 700nm to 1mm (shortest).

idk why this question was closed. It's pretty obvious, it does't lack details. It's not a sophisticated question, but this isn't PRL, it's PSE. We have the answer. The CMB is visible light (hydrogen plasma), red shifted to microwave, hence the "M" in CMB. Thus, the answer is: the size of the visible universe. We don't need all this fussing and complaining. Come on man, we don't want to turn into the C++ stack overflow, where even Bjarne Stroustrup gets downvoted.

It more a case of "How long does it take for light to be redshifted to a frequency of a microwave"? For those having difficulty understanding the question and voting to close it,  the question is about the red-shifting of light, due the the expansion of the universe. Not that hard really.

@DavidS yes that's exactly what I'm asking from 380nm to 30cm

@KDP The problem is that OP made no mention of cosmological redshift at all in the entire post. I had to help edit it in.

@X3R0 Next time, please edit clarifications into the post itself. They are not meant to be posted solely in comments. The original version of your question is decidedly unclear.
